# Peddler: List my FBM Inventory with

Tags: amazon-mws, peddler

I've installed Peddler to connect to Marketplace Web service. 
I cannot find which is the method to list my inventory (Merchant)

```
require "peddler"

client = MWS.orders(
  primary_marketplace_id: "XXXX",
  merchant_id: "XXX",
  aws_access_key_id: "XXX",
  aws_secret_access_key: "XXXXX",
)

p client.list_inventory_supply
```

**Error**

```
app.rb:30:in `<main>': undefined method `list_inventory_supply' for #<MWS::Orders::Client:0x007fd6ab9d0f60> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Did you just pull list_inventory_supply out of thin air?

You will need to request the inventory report and then once the report is ready pull it down. Look under Reports in the MWS API docs.

Comment: I cannot find an example or a "getting started" tutorial. I cannot figure out only from api docs

Answer (score 1):

First - Have you tried playing with this using Scratchpad? If not head over to https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html

You should have this bookmarked if you are working with the MWS API.

In Scratchpad you can test API calls.

Check out the following link and **READ** IT:
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html

You will see the Report that contains the SKU, ASIN, Price, and Quantity fields. You cant miss it.

The **Enumeration value** of the Report is what you use as ReportType when Requesting the Report.

The process works like this.
You request a Report by ReportType

You check to see if that Report is *DONE* (ReportProcessingStatus).

Once it is (*DONE*) you GetReport using the ReportID that is listed when you check on the Status.

You parse the Report.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this part of the error: ***for # (NoMethodError)***

What that error is saying is list_inventory_supply is not a method of MWS::Orders. (It's a method of MWS::FulfillmentInventory)

What you're looking for is this (see *client.list_inventory_supply*):

> require "peddler"
>
> client = MWS.fulfillment_inventory(   primary_marketplace_id: "XXXX", 
>   merchant_id: "XXX",   aws_access_key_id: "XXX",
>   aws_secret_access_key: "XXXXX", )
>
> p client.list_inventory_supply seller_skus: ['PF-5VZN-04XR',
>   'V4-03EY-LAL1', 'OC-TUKC-031P']